# How to add the: "Cookies EU banner" to Rails 6 site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I am trying to add this: https://github.com/Alex-D/Cookies-EU-banner to my rails 6 site. It ought to be easy, but there is something I have missed, and I can not figure out, what it is.

This is what I have done:

1. yarn add cookies-eu-banner  (no problem).
2. insert this div at the beginning of the body part (no problem - done with a partial).

```html
<div id="cookies-eu-banner" style="display: none;">
    By continuing to visit this site, you accept the use of cookies by Google Analytics for statistical purposes.
    <a href="./read-more.html" id="cookies-eu-more">Read more</a>
    <button id="cookies-eu-reject">Reject</button>
    <button id="cookies-eu-accept">Accept</button>
</div>
```

3. insert this div just before the end of the body part (also done with a partial).

```html
<%= javascript_pack_tag '../src/cookies-eu-banner' %>
<script>
    new CookiesEuBanner(function () {
        // Your code to launch when user accept cookies
    });
</script>
```

4. in application.js I have added this line:
   import('src/index')
5. in app/javascript/src/index.js I have added this line:
   import 'cookies-eu-banner'
6. I have copied the cookies-eu-banner.js script to the app/javascript/src folder.
7. Then precompiled assets, done bin/webpack and restarted the server.

However on refreshing the page, I still get either an errormessage saying that: "CookiesEuBanner is not a function", or: "Uncaught ReferenceError: cookiesEuBanner is not defined"

Any suggestions to what I have missed are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My guess would be that `javascript_pack_tag` cannot take a relative path, or that the path is wrong

Comment: I have also tried having the script directly in the app/javascript folder, and having this line in application.js: import './cookies-eu-banner'; - and then this in application.html.erb:    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'cookies-eu-banner', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>.  - same result.

Comment: Perhaps you should do this: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'cookies-eu-banner', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
For every javascript file a separate tag.

Comment: With the cookies-eu-banner directly in the packs folder, I get this in the source (html):

<script src="/packs/js/cookies-eu-banner-fb929106868b767edaac.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new CookiesEuBanner(function () {
   });
</script>

So the js file is found by webpacker.

Comment: Would I need to export CookiesEuBanner from the original js script, or do I need to do something like import CookiesEuBanner from cookies-eu-banner, to access that function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make this work with webpack/Webpacker, usage will be different than what's currently described in the cookies-eu-banner README. Your JavaScript code must be imported in the webpack dependency graph instead of embedding JS in `<script>` tags in the view.

First, make sure that following tags are in your layout to import Webpacker-bundled JavaScript and CSS:

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

The banner HTML should be in your layout/view, i.e., `<div id="cookies-eu-banner" style="display: none;">...</div>` per the README.

Then, add a JS file for initializing the banner somewhere in `app/javascript/`, (but not in `app/javascript/packs`), like `app/javascript/src/add-eu-banner.js`. Here, you'll import the library (and default css if desired) and initialize it when the DOM content has loaded:

```js
// app/javascript/src/add-eu-banner.js

import CookiesEuBanner from 'cookies-eu-banner'
import 'cookies-eu-banner/css/cookies-eu-banner.default.css'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new CookiesEuBanner(() => {
    console.log('Cookies EU Banner accepted')
  })
})
```

Now, add *that file* to the webpack dependency graph by adding an import statement in the "application.js" pack file:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import '../src/add-eu-banner'
```

That should display the banner. You might need to refresh the page or restart the webpack-dev-server depending on how you're developing locally.

I also created this as an example in a branch in my Rails 6 Webpacker demo repo: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/cookies-eu-banner

Comment: I followed your instructions, and I do get the 'Cookies EU Banner accepted' in the console log, so I am certain, your answer is correct. However, when I try to add the google analytics from the examples, I still do not get shown the banner:

Comment: I followed your instructions, and I see the 'Cookies EU Banner accepted' in the console log, so I am certain your answer is working and correct. However I still do not get to see the actual banner, when refreshing the page.

If I want to use the google analytics example, should I use jquery to add that whole code to a <div>, or just replace the console.log('Cookies EU Banner accepted') with the 'real code'?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot comment yet because of my reputation:

[@rossta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794711/10391339) 's answer is the correct one. To answer [@Mhon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789771/how-to-add-the-cookies-eu-banner-to-rails-6-site?answertab=votes#comment111064307_62794711) follow up question about how to add Google Analytics: Just adjust the code in the init of CookiesEuBanner as following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    new CookiesEuBanner(function () {
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        // Don't forget to put your own UA-XXXXXXXX-X code
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }), true; 
})
```

My banner was not showing either. Make sure that you don't already have the cookie "hasConsent=true" and/or check your browser security settings.
i.e. Firefox: [Website cookie settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-say-cookies-are-blocked-unblock-them)

Comment: Yes, thank you - I have marked Rossta's answer as accepted. It took a lot of restarts, clearing cookies etc, but I have got it working now, and Rossta answer got me on the right track.